# Count total rows from multiple queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I tie this to be one query and get the total count from all 3 queries?
Thanks

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TopicArticleMappings a
INNER JOIN ArticleAuthor b
ON A.ArticleId = B.ArticleGuid
WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM JurisdictionAuthors a
INNER JOIN Authors b
ON a.AuthorGuid = b.AuthorGuid
WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TopicConsultingEditors a
INNER JOIN tAuthors b
ON a.AuthorRef = b.AuthorRef
WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `subquery` with `union all` to combine all result-set :

```
SELECT SUM(CNT) AS Total_count
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
      FROM . . .
      UNION ALL
      SELECT . . .
      FROM . . .
      UNION ALL
      SELECT . . . 
      FROM . . .
     ) t;
```

Comment: You might want to tell the OP to alias at least the first count column to `CNT`, and to not make a typo, it's a rude enough abbreviation already.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to simply put `SELECT` in front and use subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM TopicArticleMappings a JOIN
             ArticleAuthor b
             ON A.ArticleId = B.ArticleGuid
        WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'
       ) +
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM JurisdictionAuthors a JOIN
             Authors b
             ON a.AuthorGuid = b.AuthorGuid
        WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'
       ) +
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM TopicConsultingEditors a JOIn
             tAuthors b
             ON a.AuthorRef = b.AuthorRef
        WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'
       )
```

Comment: @YogeshSharma count will never return NULL. It will return a number every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use variables instead of "union", like:

```
declare @JurisdictionAuthors int, @TopicConsultingEditors int, @TopicArticleMappings  int

SELECT @TopicArticleMappings = COUNT(*)
FROM TopicArticleMappings a
INNER JOIN ArticleAuthor b
ON A.ArticleId = B.ArticleGuid
WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'

SELECT @JurisdictionAuthors = COUNT(*) 
FROM JurisdictionAuthors a
INNER JOIN Authors b
ON a.AuthorGuid = b.AuthorGuid
WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'

SELECT @TopicConsultingEditors = COUNT(*) 
FROM TopicConsultingEditors a
INNER JOIN tAuthors b
ON a.AuthorRef = b.AuthorRef
WHERE b.AuthorGuid = '9AC4AB6E-7454-4660-97CD-93D5BC6772C3'

select @JurisdictionAuthors + @TopicConsultingEditors + @TopicArticleMappings
```